# How to make awk only run after certain headings?

Tags: awk

I have a file with tables of values under certain headings. Like so:

```
Series A
a 01 20
b 21 43
c 44 59
d 60 72

Series B
a 01 25
b 26 48
c 49 70
d 71 90
```

My question is, how can I make awk only draw information from the specified series? So if awk is told to look at "Series B", column 2, it will output that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the tables are separated by empty line(s):

```
awk '$0 ~ p, !NF {
  if (!($0 ~ p) && NF) print $c
  }' p='Series B' c=2 infile
```

`$0 ~ p, !NF` - the pair of patterns separated by a comma specify a range of records.
The first one evaluates to true if the current record $0 matches the pattern indicated by
the value of the variable p. The second one is true when the value of NF (Number of Fields)
is 0 (empty or blank line).

`if (!($0 ~ p) && NF) print $c` - if the current record doesn't match the pattern p
(i.e. skip the header), and (&&) the current record contains at least one column (`NF != 0`)
print the desired column.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to coding and I'd like to understand the code above. Does the `$0 ~ p, !NF` mean start matching if the line is the same as "p"? What is the purpose of "!NF"? Does the "if" statement mean "if the line is not the same as p AND the number of fields?", if so, why?. This must be obvious to you, but I would really appreciate any help in understanding this.

Comment: Just to be sure I get it: `$0 ~ p, !NF` means that awk will only look between "p" and an empty line, and the "if" basically means forget the header and only take valid inputs (when there is at least one column)? Would 'if (!($0 ~ p) && NF 2)' or similar mean that it only matches if the current record contains at least 3 columns?

Comment: @DeoxNa, 1 question: yes. 2 question: it should be `... && NF > 2`.

Comment: On a slightly unrelated note, I need to create 3 separate arrays, one for each of the columns. I was thinking I could make your code a function, and then have its variables change with each array, but I'm not sure how to do this. Something like `col1=x when p='SERIES' and c=1` and `col2=x when p='SERIES' and c=2`. Where "col1" and "col2" are arrays made of the output of your script for the 1st and 2nd column, respectively. I'm not sure if what I'm saying makes sense, and if it doesn't I can clarify. I didn't want to post this as a separate question because it is very much related to this one.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out how to do it. Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

If the data is separated by a blank line then you can use something like this -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
Series A
a 01 20
b 21 43
c 44 59
d 60 72

Series B
a 01 25
b 26 48
c 49 70
d 71 90
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '/Series B/,/^$/ { if (NF==3) print $2 }' file
01
26
49
71
```

Or you can do something similar in `sed`:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] sed -n '/Series B/,/^$/s/\(.*[^ ]\) \(.*[^ ]\) \(.*\)/\2/p' file
01
26
49
71
```

Comment: Nice. Range selection gets underused in awk.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this way:

```
awk -v sect="$1" -v col="$2" '
/Series/ {header = $0; next}
NF > 1 {
    set[header] = set[header]$col"|";
}
END {print set[sect];}
' $3 | tr '|' '\n'
```

I introduce associate array and temp seperator(not needed if you don't need sort on "Series", just use "\n" and omit tr), don't rely on blank line, use "|" as temp sep, use tr to transfer it back.

This is my common solution since in real life I can create custom "sorting column", then pipe to unix sort, and cut them back. Nawk(alas AIX) don't have sort and unix sort is far more superior then any hand-made sort in awk.